# C++ Remove element from vector in loop

Tags: c++, vector, set

I am trying to implement Set Class in C ++ (on Home exercise). I would like overloading operator - = for sets subtraction. Some times function return good result, but sometimes digits from set s2 are in set s1. Moreover, if you could check out the copy constructor? And tell me and tell me if it should be like this using vectors in Class. And if in Class i have vector, i have to write something in destructor? Thank You for Help!
(vector is public for tests)

My code is:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Set
{
    int n;

public:
    vector <int> set;
    Set(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            set.push_back(rand()%11);
        }
        this->n = set.size();
        remove_duplicates();
    }
    Set(const Set& obj)
    {
        n=obj.n;
        set.clear();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            set.push_back(obj.set[i]);
        }
    }
    Set& operator-=(const Set& obj)
    {
        for(auto it = set.begin(); it !=set.end(); it++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<obj.set.size(); j++)
            {
                if(set[*it]==set[j])
                {
                    it = set.erase(it);
                }
            }
        }
        return * this;
    }
    void remove_duplicates()
    {
        sort( set.begin(), set.end() );
        set.erase( unique( set.begin(), set.end() ), set.end() );
        n = set.size();
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<set.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << set[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    Set s1(5);
    Set s2(5);
    s1.print();
    s2.print();
    cout << endl;
    s1-=s2;
    s1.print();
}
```

example result;

```
2 3 6 7 9
1 3 7 9

6 7 9
```

and good result

```
1 3 5 6 7
2 4 9 10

5 6 7
```

Comment: Handy reading: [The Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You want to strive for the Rule of Zero. If all of the class's members are self-managing--they look after copying, moving and destruction--then the class needs to do nothing and should do nothing. No destructor and no copy or move special member functions. Let the compiler do all of the work for you. `int` and `vector` are self-managing, so `Set` can take advantage and remove or explicitly `default` the destructor and special member functions.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in `operator-=` is implemented wrong.

You are incrementing the `it` iteration on all loop iterations unconditionally, even on iterations that are `erase()`'ing elements, thus you end up skipping elements.

Also, you are using the element values of the target `vector` as indexes into that `vector`, which is wrong. And though you are looping through the source `vector`, you are not actually indexing into that `vector`'s elements at all.

Try this instead:

```
Set& operator-=(const Set& obj)
{
    auto it = set.begin();
    while (it != set.end())
    {
        bool erased = false;
        for(int value : obj.set)
        {
            if (*it == value)
            {
                it = set.erase(it);
                erased = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!erased)
            ++it;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Which can then be simplified using `std::find()`, eg:

```
Set& operator-=(const Set& obj)
{
    auto it = set.begin();
    while (it != set.end())
    {
        if (std::find(obj.set.begin(), obj.set.end(), *it) != obj.set.end())
            it = set.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
Set& operator-=(const Set& obj)
{
    for(int value : obj.set)
    {
        auto found = std::find(set.begin(), set.end(), value);
        if (found != set.end())
            set.erase(found);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Or, you can use `std::remove_if()` instead, eg:

```
Set& operator-=(const Set& obj)
{
    set.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            set.begin(), set.end(),
            [&](int value){
                return std::find(obj.set.begin(), obj.set.end(), value) != obj.set.end();
            }
        ),
        set.end()
    );
    return *this;
}
```

---

Also, your `n` class member is unused outside of your constructors, so it should not be in the class at all. You already know that you can use `set.size()` where needed.

Also, your copy constructor can be greatly simplified by using `vector`'s copy constructor, in which case you can actually eliminate your copy constructor altogether and let the compiler auto-generate it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, so copy constructor unnecessary? I wrote it becouse when i tried `Set s1 =s2; s1.set.pop_back()` and after print with use n in loop `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` it didn't work

Comment: "*so copy constructor unnecessary?*" - the way you are using the `vector`, yes. "*I wrote it becouse ... and after print with use `n` in loop ... it didn't work*" - did you decrement `n` after calling `pop_back()`? If not, then your print loop would index into the `vector` out of bounds. All the more reason to get rid of `n` and just use `set.size()` instead, or better a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop